# How to Capture $_SESSION NAME that perform delete into oracle history table

Tags: php, oracle, crud

I have a crud system using Oracle DB to store the data. There are two tables (the `main` table and `history`). Users have to login to the system. I already created an `update or delete` trigger from `main` to the `history` table, and it works fine for both. Now I want to capture `$_SESSION NAME` and insert it into column `ACTION_BY` in table `HISTORY` when the user deletes any row. I have no idea how to do it. Can anyone help me.

---

**proc_delete.php**

```
<?
require 'inc_instance.php';

$id  = $_POST["id"];

$user = $_SESSION['name'];

$db = Database::obtain(HDBUSER, HDBPASS, HDBNAME);
$db->connect();

$sql = "DELETE FROM CIM_TRACKING_MAIN WHERE id = '".$id."'";
$db->query($sql);

echo json_encode([$id]);

$db->close();
```

Can I directly insert session name into the `history` table when the user pushes the delete button?

This is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: You want to insert $_SESSION Name into History table after user delete something from CIM_TRACKING_MAIN ?

Comment: yes something like that

Answer (score 0):

Not sure is this the thing you want

```
$query = $db->query($sql);
if($query){ // return true if your delete query success
// Insert query into your History table here
   $sql_02 = "INSERT INTO History(ACTION_BY) VALUES ('$user')";
   if($db->query($sql_02)=== TRUE){
    // do the action you want here, if no need then remove this if statement
 }
}
```

---

But using this will cause **major security vulnerability**, try to use [prepare statement next time](https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: I have tried with if ($query == TRUE){ "insert into HISTORY where action_by = '".$user."'; } but its not work.. is that like this ?

Comment: @Shamel I edited something, take a look if its work

Comment: hi @Xun thanks for your answer, the edited answer also not work for me.I don't know why.btw thanks again.